# how to access drupal site using domain containing host ip address as prefix

Tags: 7, users

My drupal site works in local domain dev.example.com (which is configured as a virtual host).

For some reason, now I need to access the site using exactly the following address:

```
http://192.168.3.149/dev.example.com
```

where 192.168.3.149 is the IP address of the local host where the site resides.

When this address is entered, I am redirected to `http://192.168.3.149/install.php`. Looks like Drupal treats this as a new domain.

How to tell Drupal to treat these two domains identically, i.e. treat `http://192.168.3.149/dev.example.com` as an alias of `http://dev.example.com` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your site's settings might be in a multisite folder like `/sites/dev.example.com/`. When you aren't visiting via the hostname it will fall back to the settings in `/sites/default/`—check that those values are correct.